# Run Different Function based on URL Path Containing Different Strings

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on an old site that's multilingual.  All of the French content displays by taking the english URL and appending /fr/ to the URL.

Example:

English About Page = [www.example.com/about](http://www.example.com/about)
French About Page [www.examples.com/fr/about](http://www.examples.com/fr/about)

I need to run some javascript on this website but I need different javascript based on whether the person is on English or French.

Here's what I've put together but I don't trust my Javascript knowledge enough to know if this will work:

```js
if (window.location.href.indexOf("/fr/") > -1) {

  (function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    var h = document.querySelector('head') || document.body;
    s.src = 'https://acsbapp.com/apps/app/dist/js/app.js';
    s.async = true;
    s.onload = function() {
      acsbJS.init({
        statementLink: 'FR',
        footerHtml: 'FR',
        hideMobile: false,
        hideTrigger: false,
        disableBgProcess: false,
        language: 'fr',
        position: 'left',
        leadColor: '#005596',
        triggerColor: '#005596',
        triggerRadius: '50%',
        triggerPositionX: 'left',
        triggerPositionY: 'bottom',
        triggerIcon: 'people',
        triggerSize: 'medium',
        triggerOffsetX: 20,
        triggerOffsetY: 20,
        mobile: {
          triggerSize: 'small',
          triggerPositionX: 'left',
          triggerPositionY: 'center',
          triggerOffsetX: 10,
          triggerOffsetY: 0,
          triggerRadius: '50%'
        }
      });
    };
    h.appendChild(s);
  })();

  else {

    (function() {
      var s = document.createElement('script');
      var h = document.querySelector('head') || document.body;
      s.src = 'https://acsbapp.com/apps/app/dist/js/app.js';
      s.async = true;
      s.onload = function() {
        acsbJS.init({
          statementLink: 'en',
          footerHtml: 'en',
          hideMobile: false,
          hideTrigger: false,
          disableBgProcess: false,
          language: 'en',
          position: 'left',
          leadColor: '#005596',
          triggerColor: '#005596',
          triggerRadius: '50%',
          triggerPositionX: 'left',
          triggerPositionY: 'bottom',
          triggerIcon: 'people',
          triggerSize: 'medium',
          triggerOffsetX: 20,
          triggerOffsetY: 20,
          mobile: {
            triggerSize: 'small',
            triggerPositionX: 'left',
            triggerPositionY: 'center',
            triggerOffsetX: 10,
            triggerOffsetY: 0,
            triggerRadius: '50%'
          }
        });
      };
      h.appendChild(s);
    })();


  }

}
```

I need to add the fixed code to this

```js
!function(){var e=document.querySelector(".main-carousel");if(e){var t=new Flickity(e,{wrapAround:!0,prevNextButtons:!1,imagesLoaded:!0});document.querySelector(".rotator__prev-next--prev").addEventListener("click",function(e){t.previous()}),document.querySelector(".rotator__prev-next--next").addEventListener("click",function(){t.next()})}var n=document.querySelector(".skip-nav-btn"),o=document.querySelector("main");n.addEventListener("click",function(){o.focus()}),window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var e=window.location.pathname.split("/"),t="/"+e.slice(1,e.length-1).join("/"),n=this.document.querySelector(".header-menu__item__link[href='"+t+"']");n&&n.classList.add("header-menu__item__link--active")});for(var d=document.querySelectorAll(".header-menu__item__link"),i=0;i<d.length;i++)d[i].addEventListener("touchstart",function(e){e.target.nextSibling&&e.target.nextSibling.classList.contains("dropdown")&&document.activeElement!=e.target&&window.innerWidth>=1024&&(e.preventDefault(),e.target.focus())});var r=document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown__item__link"),s=document.body;document.querySelector(".menu-toggle").addEventListener("click",function(){s.classList.contains("menu-expanded")?(s.classList.remove("menu-expanded"),s.classList.add("menu-closed")):(s.classList.add("menu-expanded"),s.classList.remove("menu-closed"))});for(i=0;i<r.length;i++)r[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){s.classList.remove("menu-expanded"),s.classList.add("menu-closed")}),r[i].addEventListener("focus",function(e){e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("dropdown-item-focused")}),r[i].addEventListener("blur",function(e){e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("dropdown-item-focused")});window.addEventListener("resize",function(){s.classList.contains("menu-expanded")&&this.window.innerWidth>=1024&&(s.classList.remove("menu-expanded"),s.classList.add("menu-closed"))});var c=document.querySelector(".filter__button"),a=document.querySelector(".filter__select"),l=document.querySelectorAll(".filter__item"),u=document.querySelector(".products"),m=document.querySelectorAll(".products__item");a&&a.addEventListener("change",function(e){u.classList.add("products--loading"),setTimeout(function(){v(a.value,l[a.selectedIndex].innerHTML),u.classList.remove("products--loading")},200)});for(i=0;i<l.length;i++)l[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){u.classList.add("products--loading"),setTimeout(function(){v(e.target.value,e.target.innerHTML),u.classList.remove("products--loading")},200)}),l[i].addEventListener("touchstart",function(e){u.classList.add("products--loading"),setTimeout(function(){v(e.target.value,e.target.innerHTML),u.classList.remove("products--loading")},200)});function v(e,t){e=e.toUpperCase();for(var n=0;n<l.length;n++)l[n].innerHTML===t?l[n].classList.add("filter__item--active"):l[n].classList.remove("filter__item--active");if(c.innerHTML=t+"<svg"+c.innerHTML.split("<svg")[1],"ALL"===e)for(n=0;n<m.length;n++)m[n].classList.remove("products__item--hidden");else for(n=0;n<m.length;n++)m[n].getAttribute("data-category")==="products__item--"+e.toLowerCase()?m[n].classList.remove("products__item--hidden"):m[n].classList.add("products__item--hidden")}var L=document.querySelector(".anchor#main");function p(){var e=document.querySelector(".header").clientHeight,t=document.querySelector(".footer").clientHeight;document.body.style.paddingTop=e+"px",document.body.style.paddingBottom=t+"px",L.style.top=-e+"px"}p(),window.addEventListener("resize",p)}();
```

Comment: Did you try it to see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

DRY: Don't repeat yourself

Also set the src AFTER the onload event handler

```js
const lang = window.location.href.indexOf("/fr/") > -1 ? "fr" : "en";
const statementLink = lang === "fr" ? "fr.com" : "en.com";
const footerHTML = lang === "fr" ? "French123 " : "English123 ";
(function() {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  var h = document.querySelector('head');
  s.onload = function() {
    acsbJS.init({
      statementLink: statementLink ,
      footerHtml: footerHTML ,
      hideMobile: false,
      hideTrigger: false,
      disableBgProcess: false,
      language: lang,
      position: 'left',
      leadColor: '#005596',
      triggerColor: '#005596',
      triggerRadius: '50%',
      triggerPositionX: 'left',
      triggerPositionY: 'bottom',
      triggerIcon: 'people',
      triggerSize: 'medium',
      triggerOffsetX: 20,
      triggerOffsetY: 20,
      mobile: {
        triggerSize: 'small',
        triggerPositionX: 'left',
        triggerPositionY: 'center',
        triggerOffsetX: 10,
        triggerOffsetY: 0,
        triggerRadius: '50%'
      }
    });
  };
  s.src = 'https://acsbapp.com/apps/app/dist/js/app.js';
  h.appendChild(s);
})();
```

Just add the code to after `window.addEventListener("resize",p)}();`

Comment: I appreciate this.  

One thing, and I should have clarified it is that:

statementLink and footerHtml should not equal 'fr' or 'en'.  They should be unique to language.  

IE: 

StatementLink should be www.english.com for English 
StatementLink should be www.french.com for French

footerHTML should be English123 for English
footerHTML should be French123 for French. 

Thank you for your quick help.

Comment: That is trivial. See update

Comment: Thanks so much.  Lastly, it looks like there's already a lot of javascript in this file so I need to somehow add that code to the existing JS which is begins with:

`!function(){var e=document.querySelector(".main-carousel");`

and ends at 

`;function p(){var e=document.querySelector(".header").clientHeight,t=document.querySelector(".footer").clientHeight;document.body.style.paddingTop=e+"px",document.body.style.paddingBottom=t+"px",L.style.top=-e+"px"}p(),window.addEventListener("resize",p)}();`

I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Pls update your question instead of posting unformatted code in a comment

Comment: No problem, I've done that.  Thank you so much. I am very grateful

Comment: @Bridge Sorry I did not mean for you to CHANGE the question completely.
Your code is minified. Just add my code after the end of your existing code